# How do I make a PSGI program do costly initialisation only once per process, not per thread?

Tags: multithreading, perl, psgi

cross-post: http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1191821

Consider `app.psgi`:

```
#!perl
use 5.024;
use strictures;
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);

sub mock_connect {
    my $how_long_it_takes = 3 + rand;
    sleep $how_long_it_takes;
    return $how_long_it_takes;
}
sub main {
    state $db_handle = mock_connect($dsn);
    return sub { [200, [], ["connect took $db_handle seconds\n"]] };
}
my $dsn = 'dbi:blahblah'; # from config file
my $app = main($dsn);
```

Measuring `plackup` (`HTTP::Server::PSGI: Accepting connections at http://0:5000/`):

```
› perl -MBenchmark=timeit,timestr,:hireswallclock -E"say timestr timeit 10, sub { system q(curl http://localhost:5000) }"
connect took 3.0299610154043 seconds
connect took 3.0299610154043 seconds
connect took 3.0299610154043 seconds
connect took 3.0299610154043 seconds
connect took 3.0299610154043 seconds
connect took 3.0299610154043 seconds
connect took 3.0299610154043 seconds
connect took 3.0299610154043 seconds
connect took 3.0299610154043 seconds
connect took 3.0299610154043 seconds
2.93921 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr +  0.06 sys =  0.09 CPU) @ 107.53/s (n=10)
```

Measuring `thrall` (`Starting Thrall/0.0305 (MSWin32) http server listening at port 5000`):

```
› perl -MBenchmark=timeit,timestr,:hireswallclock -E"say timestr timeit 10, sub { system q(curl http://localhost:5000) }"
connect took 3.77111188120125 seconds
connect took 3.15455510265111 seconds
connect took 3.77111188120125 seconds
connect took 3.15455510265111 seconds
connect took 3.77111188120125 seconds
connect took 3.64333342488772 seconds
connect took 3.15455510265111 seconds
connect took 3.77111188120125 seconds
connect took 3.85268922343767 seconds
connect took 3.64333342488772 seconds
17.4764 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr +  0.09 sys =  0.11 CPU) @ 90.91/s (n=10)
```

This performance is not acceptable because the initialisation happens several times, despite the `state` variable. How do you make it so it happens only once?

Comment: Do you just call them with `thrall app.psgi` and `plackup app.psgi` and default settings?

Comment: Yes, I'm executing just `plackup` and `thrall` without any arguments.

Comment: My guess is something with your environment. I tried your code (perl 5.22.1) and it works perfectly. I have the 3 seconds wait when launching the app, then identical values for $dsn, if I use thrall or not.

Comment: Sorry, but why do you use `use 5.024;`? `state` was only available since 5.10.

Comment: LSerni, you're confusing *decimal* and *dotted decimal* version types. [perldoc version](http://p3rl.org/version#TYPES-OF-VERSION-OBJECTS) ; [perldoc -f use](http://p3rl.org/use)

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, the program `thrall` hard-coded a "loader" parameter in its configuration section:

```
my $runner = Plack::Runner->new(
    server     => 'Thrall',
    env        => 'deployment',
    loader     => 'Delayed',
    version_cb => \&version,
);

$runner->parse_options(@ARGV);
```

That string `"Delayed"` refers to the module `Plack::Loader::Delayed`, which delays the loading of .psgi files until first request comes. That would match your benchmarking result. (If you re-run the benchmark again without killing thrall, you'll see identical output).

You may try running `thrall -L +Plack::Loader app.psgi`, which reverts the "loader" parameter to the default value hard-coded in `Plack::Runner`.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this what the `--preload-app` option to [Starman](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Starman) does?